# glassfish starts only from the netbeans IDE and not from the command prompt

Tags: glassfish, redhat, java-6, glassfish-3

i have installed the netbeans version 6.8 with glassfish version 3 on a redhat machine.
the thing is that when i try starting/stopping the glassfish via the netbeans, it works fine, BUT when i try starting the glassfish via:

> ./asadmin stop-domain domain1

i get the error 
"GlassFish requires Java SE version 6.  Your JDK is version 4"

i have got only one JDK instance installed

> rpm -qa | grep jdk

will return "jdk-1.6.0_18-fcs"

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the environment variable `AS_JAVA` to point to your 1.6 JDK. (asadmin will use `bin/java` within that directory). `AS_JAVA` must be set in `glassfish/config/asenv.conf`